# Postgres - access pg_config_manual.h file or modify the 'NAMEDATALEN' value using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have been wondering since a long time on how to increase the **max_identifier_length** for postgres.

I have an existing DB (in MS SQL Server) which we are migrating to Postgres, there are objects that are defined having names with a length of more than 63 chars, but because Postgres default limit is 63 chars so I am not able to use those objects as is.

Read in multiple articles, modifying the '**NAMEDATALEN**' value in **pg_config_manual.h** will work.  But challenge that I am facing is that I do not see **pg_config_manual.h** when I am working on postgres using a docker container .

Any help on how to access **pg_config_manual.h** file or modify the '**NAMEDATALEN**' value using docker?

Comment: you can only achieve that if you **compile** Postgres yourself after you changed the source file `pg_config_manual.h`

Comment: But my real question here is that I am not able to find the file when instantiating postgres through docker, how do I locate that file at first place.

Comment: It's not a configuration file, it's part of the source code. So you need to download the source: https://github.com/postgres/postgres

Comment: Still seeing issues.

Comment: I pulled the source code from git, modified pg_config_manual.h as per my requirement, now when I try to build the code it throws me few 'missing file' errors.
Any idea how these errors might be resolved?

Comment: -- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/fe_utils/psqlscan.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/interfaces/ecpg/preproc/pgc.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/interfaces/ecpg/preproc/preproc.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/backend/bootstrap/bootparse.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/test/isolation/specparse.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/bin/pgbench/exprparse.c': No such file or directory

Comment: -- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/bin/psql/psqlscanslash.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/backend/parser/gram.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/backend/parser/scan.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/backend/replication/repl_gram.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/backend/replication/syncrep_gram.c': No such file or directory

Comment: -- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/backend/utils/adt/jsonpath_gram.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'contrib/cube/cubeparse.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'contrib/seg/segparse.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open source file: 'src/pl/plpgsql/src/pl_gram.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open include file: 'preproc.h': No such file or directory

Comment: -- C1083 Cannot open include file: 'preproc.h': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open include file: 'parser/gram.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src/backend/parser/parser.c)
-- C1083 Cannot open include file: 'guc-file.c': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open include file: 'preproc.h': No such file or directory
-- C1083 Cannot open include file: 'preproc.h': No such file or directory

Comment: -- C1083 Cannot open include file: 'pl_gram.h': No such file or directory
-- LNK1181 cannot open input file 'Debug\libpgfeutils\libpgfeutils.lib'
-- LNK1181 cannot open input file 'Debug\postgres\postgres.lib'